# How to use foreach with a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We need the ability to show a message on our website if our customer service contact center is closed. I'm trying to clean up the code which checks to see if the current day is a holiday.

In the past I have used a variable for each holiday and an if statement for each holiday. That is a lot of code and it looked sloppy and unprofessional. I've been reading up on multidimensional arrays and it looks like this could be a viable solution.

---

Here's a sample of my array:

```
//Store Holidays in multidimensional array
$holidays = array
(
  "NewYearsDay"=>array
    (
      "Date"=>"01-01-2014",
      "Closed"=>"Yes"
    ),
  "MartinLutherKingJrDay"=>array
    (
      "Date"=>"01-21-2013,
      "Closed"=>"Yes"
    )
);
```

This gives me the following (which is good - i have no problem with this part)

```
Array
(
    [NewYearsDay] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 01-01-2014
            [Closed] => Yes
        )

    [MartinLutherKingJrDay] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 01-21-2013
            [Closed] => Yes
        )

)
```

However, when I use a `foreach` loop I only get the names of the holidays. I want to get the date and closed info.

```
foreach ($holidays as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
```

Only gives me: 
`NewYearsDayMartinLutherKingJrDay` (the spacing issue I can deal with later)

I would like to eventually be able to do something like this:

```
//loop through the array and do this for each iteration:
if ((NewYearsDay['date'] == date('d-m-Y')) && (NewYearsDay['closed'] == Yes)) {
    $status = "closed";
}
```

Comment: You could nest foreach loops or use recursion

Comment: @Joren Not in this case; the data isn't recursive

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use the dates as the keys? then you can say if(!empty($holidays[date('Y-m-d')]) to determine if it is a holiday rather than having to foreach through holidays.

Comment: Also, just a note, since you're new to this:  This is an array that contains other arrays.  "Multidimensional arrays" aren't their own data structure, it's just a term for a commonly-used structure.  That should provide a hint as to why `$value` is important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As diegoperini has noted above, here's a slightly more documented version:

```
foreach ($holidays as $name => $value) {
    // $name should be there, it contains your "MartinLutherKingDay" etc, 
    // could be handy.
    // although I'd put the formatted display name into your array:
    // $value['name'] = 'Martin Luther King Day';
    list($date, $closed) = $value;

    if ($date == date('d-m-Y')) && ($closed == 'Yes')) {
        // if you find what you want, and you only want one, you can skip
        // the rest of the foreach
        $status = "closed";
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Omit `$key` and use `$value` to reach your data.

```
foreach ($holidays as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
    if (($value['date'] == date('d-m-Y')) && ($value['closed'] == 'Yes')) {
        $status = "closed";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you still need $key while specifying the iteration though.

Comment: Unless required by program logic, it is optional.

Comment: Got it! I understand the $key/$value aspect of foreach now. I was a little confused about them before this post. Thank you!

Comment: although $key is not essential, in this case it might be a handy thing to have since it contains the holiday name?

Comment: Although php parser optimizes memory by not initializing unused variables, it is good practice to omit them completely unless program logic requires them within the loop.